# "Out of interest for/out of interest in"

Tags: prepositions

I am quite unsure about which preposition is correct, but I am aware that **"interest"** is usually followed by "**in**".

For example:

> "I've been **interested in** sports ever since I was young"

Though I am not sure if I should say

> "I study ___ out of pure **interest in** the language."

Or

> "I study___ out of pure **interest for** the language."

Answer (score 2):

Based on the collocations, *in* is a lot more common. I would consider a language more in the categories of *matter* and *subjects* than the likely money related terms that are usually collocating with *interest for.* So unless you are paying interest, stick with *interest in.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually did stick to "in" because ultimately it felt more natural, but it's good to have clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In the COCA corpus, the preposition 'in' can be found 17 times, but the preposition 'for' 6 times. It doesn't look like there is a big difference between them, but 'in' is preferred in usage.